# How to declare the List?

Tags: android, list

I save all the application character in `R.string`.
Now I want to save the R.string character in a List.

How to declare the List?

I use

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
list.add(R.string.helloworld);
```

And

```
List<integer> list = new ArrayList<integer>();
list.add(R.string.helloworld);
```

But I can not add it.

How to do this?

Comment: Include the compiler errors *and* the desired result.

Comment: This is not a pertinent question, there are many tutorials on google about this. Please next time try to search on the web before posting a question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your declaration is correct, there are problems with `R.string.helloworld`. This is in fact a `static int` (declaration of it is in `R.java` file). Remember to import `java.util` for `List` and `ArrayList`. If you are in Eclipse, press <kbd>Ctrl + Shift + O</kbd> to organize imports.

Use `getString(R.string.helloworld)`:

[String Resources](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource.html)

So your code will look like:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;    

List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
list.add(getResources().getString(R.string.helloworld));
```

Answer (score 2):

```
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    list.add(getResources().getString(R.string.helloworld));

    List<Integer> list1 = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    list1.add(R.string.helloworld);
```

Answer (score 1):

try this...

add import as well

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

List<String> lst = new  ArrayList<String>();
```

To Add

```
lst.add(getResources().getString(R.string.helloworld));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
  List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
  list.add(getResources().getString(R.string.helloworld));
```

may this helps you